# c++ trouble with regex , need info

Tags: c++, regex

So i want to check from a .txt file if there are valid proxies in it and i've been trying to get some matches without the regex ever working, i've decided to try a different approach, but i don't seem to understand anything with c++ regex, i don't understand how it's so different and poop,
i either get a segmentation error 11 or no matches at all.

```
regex r("[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]].[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]].[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]].[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]:[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]");
        //regex r("[[:digit:]]{1,3}(.[[:digit:]]{1,3}){3}:[[:digit:]]{1,5}");

        smatch sm;
        if ( regex_search(text,sm,r) )
        {
            //we've got a match
        }
```

Hope i can get some help

Answer (score 1):

With regexes, the best way to deal with them is to start very small and build them up. Maybe start with just matching a single digit, then when you have that matching, match between one and three digits, then match between one and three digits followed by a full stop.

You should be warned that regex is relatively recent in the C++ standard library so it may not work at all on your system. If that's a problem for you, boost::regex will work.

you may also like to use literal raw strings R"(\d{1,3}.)" to encode your regex to avoid having to double up on backslashes "\d{1,3}\." due to the escaping in regular C strings. Start with the three chars R"(  and end with the two )"

R"(\d{1,3}.)" might get you 1-3 digits folowed by a .

Comment: i've tried r("(\d{1,3}.) and i still get a segmentation error :(

Comment: Did you start with matching a single digit? The regex line you've supplied there won't compile. You aren't using raw string literals and you haven't escaped the backslash. This is programming, you have to be very, precise.